Error 500 for PdfWriter iText 8.0.5 / Java/ Tomcat
I want to create a PDF in a servlet Java8/Tomcat9.0 using iText 8.0.5
I got the sample class here. Compilation is ok but when I load the page I get an error 500.
The jar files are present on my tomcat : E:\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\Thanact\WEB-INF\lib
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.colors.ColorConstants;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Table;
import com.itextpdf.layout.properties.UnitValue;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Cell;
import com.itextpdf.layout.properties.TextAlignment;
import com.itextpdf.layout.borders.SolidBorder; 

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.OutputStream;

public class EtiquettesServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            // Test si la classe PdfWriter est bien chargée
            Class.forName("com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter");
            System.out.println("Classe PdfWriter trouvée !");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Classe PdfWriter non trouvée !");
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Classe PdfWriter non trouvée !");
            return;
        }

        // Le reste du code pour générer le PDF
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=etiquettes.pdf");

        try {
            PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(response.getOutputStream());
            PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
            Document document = new Document(pdf);
            document.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));
            document.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Erreur lors de la génération du PDF : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    }
}

The web page shows :
cause mère
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.<clinit>(PdfOutputStream.java:48)

But in the tomcat stdout log I see my iText classes.
How can I fix this ?
/E:/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/Thanact/WEB-INF/classes/
/E:/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/Thanact/WEB-INF/lib/commons-8.0.5.jar
/E:/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/Thanact/WEB-INF/lib/gson-2.2.2.jar
/E:/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/Thanact/WEB-INF/lib/io-8.0.5.jar
/E:/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/Thanact/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
/E:/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/Thanact/WEB-INF/lib/jstl_1.2.5.jar
/E:/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/Thanact/WEB-INF/lib/kernel-8.0.5.jar
/E:/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/Thanact/WEB-INF/lib/layout-8.0.5.jar
/E:/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/Thanact/WEB-INF/lib/ojdbc6.jar
/E:/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/Thanact/WEB-INF/lib/sqljdbc.jar
/E:/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/Thanact/WEB-INF/lib/taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.5.jar
/E:/Tomcat%209.0/webapps/Thanact/WEB-INF/lib/taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.5.jar


Answer
You need to download the following files and put them under WEB-INF/lib:

slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.36/slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar)
logback-classic-1.2.13.jar (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.13/logback-classic-1.2.13.jar)
logback-core-1.2.13.jar (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.13/logback-core-1.2.13.jar)

The process of finding the solution:
Your error message:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream.<clinit>(PdfOutputStream.java:48)

It means that itextpdf cannot find the class related to slf4j. It means that itextpdf depends on slf4j.
iText 8.0.5 Java can be found on Github iText Core/Community 8.0.5. (https://github.com/itext/itext-java/releases)
find Asserts ,

download iText-Core-8.0.5.zip
unzip iText-Core-8.0.5.zip,
use text editor or browser open all xxx.pom files.
in xxx.pom , search slf4j and logback

find root-8.0.5.pom



    <logback.version>1.2.13</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.36</slf4j.version>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>${logback.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

Then you can use google maven logback 1.2.13 and maven slf4j 1.7.36 to find the mvnrepository.com related links in the results, and then download the jar.
Appendix - 1
In addition, iText 8.5 also requires the following jars:

bc-fips-1.0.2.4.jar     (org.bouncycastle:bc-fips:1.0.2.4)
bcpkix-fips-1.0.7.jar   (org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-fips:1.0.7)
bcpkix-jdk18on-1.78.jar (org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk18on:1.78)
bcprov-jdk18on-1.78.jar (org.bouncycastle:bcutil-jdk18on:1.78)
bcutil-jdk18on-1.78.jar (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.78)

Appendix - 2 - install download iText jar into local maven repo.
Prerequisites:



JDK has been installed and configured.




Maven has been installed and configured.



Install all iText jar on local maven repo:
Step 1 - Download iText-Core-8.0.5.zip

download iText-Core-8.0.5.zip (https://github.com/itext/itext-java/releases/download/8.0.5/iText-Core-8.0.5.zip)

Step 2 - unzip iText-Core-8.0.5.zip

unzip iText-Core-8.0.5.zip
Output is iText-Core-8.0.5 directory

Step 3 - Create maven-install-jar shell or batch file

Step 3-1 - Open Terminal or CMD.exe
Step 3-2 - Change to iText-Core-8.0.5 directory

command  cd iText-Core-8.0.5


Step 3-3 - Create  maven-install-jar File - Windows

Create file:  maven-install-jar.bat
@echo off
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=%1.jar -DpomFile=%1.pom


Step 3-4 - Create  maven-install-jar File - Linux

Create file:  maven-install-jar
#!/bin/bash
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=$1.jar -DpomFile=$1.pom


Linux run command: chmod u+x maven-install-jar
Linux run command:

export PATH=`pwd`:$PATH

(In the terminal, the current location is in the iText-Core-8.0.5 directory.)

Step 4 : run command install all iText pom and jar into local maven repo

Same command for Windows and Linux
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=root-8.0.5.pom -DgroupId=com.itextpdf -DartifactId=root -Dversion=8.0.5 -Dpackaging=pom

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=itext7-core-8.0.5.pom -DgroupId=com.itextpdf -DartifactId=itext7-core -Dversion=8.0.5 -Dpackaging=pom

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=itext-core-8.0.5.pom -DgroupId=com.itextpdf -DartifactId=itext-core -Dversion=8.0.5 -Dpackaging=pom

maven-install-jar barcodes-8.0.5
maven-install-jar bouncy-castle-adapter-8.0.5
maven-install-jar bouncy-castle-connector-8.0.5
maven-install-jar bouncy-castle-fips-adapter-8.0.5
maven-install-jar commons-8.0.5
maven-install-jar font-asian-8.0.5
maven-install-jar forms-8.0.5
maven-install-jar hyph-8.0.5
maven-install-jar io-8.0.5
maven-install-jar kernel-8.0.5
maven-install-jar layout-8.0.5
maven-install-jar pdfa-8.0.5
maven-install-jar pdftest-8.0.5
maven-install-jar pdfua-8.0.5
maven-install-jar sign-8.0.5
maven-install-jar styled-xml-parser-8.0.5
maven-install-jar svg-8.0.5

Now your iText Maven Project:
pom.xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>barcodes</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
            <!--
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/barcodes-8.0.5.jar</systemPath>
            -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>bouncy-castle-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
            <!--
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/bouncy-castle-adapter-8.0.5.jar</systemPath>
            -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>bouncy-castle-connector</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
            <!--
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/bouncy-castle-connector-8.0.5.jar</systemPath>
            -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>bouncy-castle-fips-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
            <!--
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/bouncy-castle-fips-adapter-8.0.5.jar</systemPath>
            -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
            <!--
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/commons-8.0.5.jar</systemPath>
            -->
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>font-asian</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
            <!--
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/font-asian-8.0.5.jar</systemPath>
            -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
            <!--
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/forms-8.0.5.jar</systemPath>
            -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>hyph</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
            <!--
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/hyph-8.0.5.jar</systemPath>
            -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>io</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
            <!--
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/io-8.0.5.jar</systemPath>
            -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
            <!--
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/kernel-8.0.5.jar</systemPath>
            -->
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
            <!--
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/layout-8.0.5.jar</systemPath>
            -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfa</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
            <!--
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/pdfa-8.0.5.jar</systemPath>
            -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfua</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
            <!--
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/pdfua-8.0.5.jar</systemPath>
            -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>sign</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
            <!--
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/sign-8.0.5.jar</systemPath>
            -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>styled-xml-parser</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
            <!--
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/styled-xml-parser-8.0.5.jar</systemPath>
            -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>svg</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.5</version>
            <!--
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/lib-jar-itext/svg-8.0.5.jar</systemPath>
            -->
        </dependency>



You are good, it was on spot and very clear, thank you !
I also needed logback-core-1.2.13 for logback-classic but thanks to your guidance I was able to identify and fix it easily.
Thanks again :)

download link: logback-classic-1.2.13.jar (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.13/logback-classic-1.2.13.jar)
logback-core-1.2.13.jar (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.13/logback-core-1.2.13.jar) is in the answer.
